# Spring Elasticsearch, create a apps trending request

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch, I have list of apk with category apps and games and a lot of metadata.
I have to return the list of top trading apk by category. My request must take into account and sort by best combination of:

1. Most downloaded apk (apps or games) in the current week
2. Most positively rated
3. Most commented

How could I do this kind of request please ?
I use spring 2.2 and spring elastic search 3.2.4.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Document(indexName = "apk")
public class Apk {

    @Id //The unique id
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private Rating rating = new Rating();

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private List<Review> userReview = new ArrayList<>();

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private Category category;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private SubCategory subCategory;

    private ApkStatus status = ApkStatus.INITIATED;

    private Set<String> dependencies = new HashSet<>();

    private Set<String> permissions = new HashSet<>();
    private String changes;
    private Long companyId;
    private String description;
    private String displayName;

    private String packageName = "unknown";
    private BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(0);
    private String shortDescription;
    private String versionName = "unknown";
    private String videoUrl;
    private Boolean containsAds;
    private Boolean isFree=false;
    private long versionCode = 0;
    private String minSdkVersion;
    private String targetSdkVersion;
    private String maxSdkVersion;
    private long installs;
    private long unInstalls;
    private long size;
    private String apkName;
    private String repositoryGeneratedId;

    private String iconPath;  

    private String iconDownloadUrl;
    
    private String apkPath;  

    private String apkDownloadUrl;

    private String installHistoryString;
    private String unInstallHistoryString;
    
    @Transient
    private NavigableMap<String, Integer> installHistory = new TreeMap<>();
    @Transient
    private NavigableMap<String, Integer> unInstallHistory = new TreeMap<>();

    private Map<String, TranslatedMetadata> translatedMetadataList = new TreeMap<>();
    
    LocalizedLanguage defaultLanguage;
    
    private Date updateDate = new Date();
    private Date createDate = new Date();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a Spring Data JPA annotated class. How do you store your data in Elasticsearch?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch this is a mistake. I corrected the class